# Nvidia GPU driver errors downloading and installing

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, gpu-driver

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on my PC.

I'm trying to install nvidia-driver-470-server, but I'm getting errors.

I've tried to download and install the drivers in 2 different ways.
The first with the additional drivers GUI, and the second one using terminal command `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-470-server`.

In the both ways I'm getting error messages and its going like that:

First error page:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Second error page:

[image: Screenshot 2]

I already tried to using `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get upgrade` with out success. Any one have another solution?

Comment: Hello. You do have a pretty clear error message the mirror at il is not available. Have you tried another mirror? The errors you have posted only seem to come from the upgrade command.

Comment: Here is the list of all the mirrors. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Comment: Yes its worked. Thank you soo much. @David

Comment: Great I did make it an answer so you could accept it and others can benefit from it as well. Since you are new there is an accept button you can use to make it an accepted answer.

Comment: @ShimriA While I'm happy you got your question answered, I would encourage you to read [why we ask that you not post textual error messages (and other text output) as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your errors I can see they all start with Il. This indicates the mirror you are using.

You do have a pretty clear error message the mirror at Il is not available.

Have you tried another mirror? The errors you have posted only seem to come from the upgrade command.

Here is the Official URL of all the mirrors. Try another and see if that fixes it.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors