# i am doing cross compilation between that i try to update and i got this error and i can't able to cross compile arm64 on my ubantu

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-center, update-manager

so i run sudo apt-get update
and it gives me
.....

Can not add an empty (zero-length) key to the cache
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 43.255.166.254 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 43.255.166.254 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 43.255.166.254 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

what should i have to do
and how to do cross compilation of arm64 on that please guide me

Comment: Hello. this question has been asked many times before. The error is clear the URL is not found. See this question and accepted answer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402467/nvidia-gpu-driver-errors-downloading-and-installing/1402476#1402476

Comment: The very confusing title has noting to do with the body of the question. The title should have been apt-get update fails.